# lxml iterparse with file fails

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I am running a python program to get a subtree from XML file. Following is the code that I am running to get the subtree from tag .

Sample file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nc:data xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <system xmlns="abc.org">
        <context>
            <name>context_1</name>
            <host>
                <name>Name_Node</name>
                <tag1>
                    <name>ABC</name>
                    <tag2>PQR</tag2>
                </tag1>
            </host> 
        </context>
    </system>
</nc:data>
```

and function for iterparse

```
class xml_file_generation: 

    def xml_parse_new(self):
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse('sample.xml', events=events, tag="context"):
                print "In loop"
                print ET.tostring(elem)
                print("%s" % (elem.tag))
                elem.close()


test = xml_file_generation()
test.xml_parse_new()
```

But this code returns nothing to display.

If I run the same code as below, output is as expected one :

```
xml = '''\
      <root>
        <element key='value'>text</element>
        <element>text</element>tail
        <empty-element xmlns="testns" />
        <testtag>abc</testtag>
      </root>
      '''

events = ("start", "end")
context = ET.iterparse(StringIO(xml),  events=events, tag='testtag')
for action, elem in context:
    print action, elem.tag
    print elem.text
```

Please suggest a solution if possible.

Comment: Are you calling the function in the first case? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @anand Yes I am calling it.. Updating the same in question !!

Comment: What is the output you are getting in first case?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: I getting absolutely nothing as Output. I have also tried putting print "In loop" in the defined function. Even that is not getting printed !!

Comment: That is not the complete code ,is it? You seem to be calling `xml_parse_new()` , but the definition accepts a `self` argument. Are you sure you are calling the correct method? SEems like the method is inside some class. Can you please link to or update the complete code?

Comment: @anand Yes I just did !! Can you please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml, your element - `<context>` - has a namespace - `'abc.org'` , which it gets from its parent element. In such cases, when specifying the tagname in `tag` argument, you also need to specify the namespace.

And not really, sure what you meant by `elem.close()` , but remove it , `Element` has no method `close()` .

Try the below Example -

```
class xml_file_generation: 
    def xml_parse_new(self):
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse('a.xml', events=events, tag="{abc.org}context"):
                print("In loop")
                print(ET.tostring(elem))
                print("%s" % (elem.tag))


test = xml_file_generation()
test.xml_parse_new()
```